# Migrating PySpark groupby collect_set to Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am migrating a pySpark implementation to Pandas. In order to transform a large dataset, I am using `dask` package.

`pySpark` implementation:

```
df.groupBy('Key').agg(collect_set('ColumnA').alias('Items'), collect_set('ColumnB').alias('DocumentId'))
```

to `Pandas`

```
df.groupby("Key")[['ColumnA','ColumnB']].agg(set).reset_index()
```

Then I am renaming the column in separate lines.

The above code in Dask gives error `ValueError: unknown aggregate set` which makes sense because Dask only supports `['sum', 'mean', 'max', 'min', list]` Pandas function.

Is there a way to have a custom implementation for `set`?

Comment: Just curious to know the usecase for this for my learning if you dont mind :) . Basically why dask when you have spark? Also what is the size of the tables (approx) you want to do this for

Comment: Yeah sure. I will be using these datasets on Azure ML and the platform is not Spark friendly. It is around 16gbs of data which times out with Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

The analogous operation in Dask would be the `groupby.unique` operation (though you'll get a list in each row, rather than a set).

Dask doesn't currently appear to expose this functionality on Dataframe groupby objects, though it does expose it on Series groupby objects. This would make an excellent [feature request](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new/choose).

For now, you could do:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
​
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Key":[0,0,1,1],
    "ColumnA": [10,10,11,11],
    "ColumnB": [8,12,16,16]
})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, 1)
​
result = ddf.groupby("Key").ColumnA.unique()
result = result.to_frame()
result["ColumnB"] = ddf.groupby("Key").ColumnB.unique()
​
print(result.compute(), "\n")
print(df.groupby("Key")[['ColumnA','ColumnB']].agg(set).reset_index())
    ColumnA  ColumnB
Key                 
0      [10]  [8, 12]
1      [11]     [16] 

   Key ColumnA  ColumnB
0    0    {10}  {8, 12}
1    1    {11}     {16}
```